# node.js simple project: ReferenceError: <ClassName> is not defined

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I try to learn Node.js (ES6) but fail on `require`

This is my structure:

[image]

*baseModel.js*

```
"use strict";

class BaseModel {
  constructor(options = {}, data = []) { // class constructor
      this.name = 'Base'
      this.url = 'http://azat.co/api'
      this.data = data
      this.options = options
    }

    getName() { // class method
        console.log(`Class name: ${this.name}`)
    }
}
```

*AccountModel.js*

```
"use strict";

require('./baseModel.js');

class AccountModel extends BaseModel {
    constructor(options, data) {

    super({private: true}, ['32113123123', '524214691']) //call the parent method with super
      this.name += 'Account Model'
      this.url +='/accounts/'
    }


    get accountsData() { //calculated attribute getter
    // ... make XHR
        return this.data
    }

}
```

*main.js*

```
"use strict";

require('./AccountModel.js');

let accounts = new AccountModel(5)

accounts.getName()

console.log('Data is %s', accounts.accountsData);
```

Now I run: `node --harmony-default-parameters  main.js`

and get error:

> ReferenceError: BaseModel is not defined
>       at Object. (/Users/tamirscherzer/POC/projects/NodeJS/tutorials/classes/AccountModel.js:5:28)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object. (/Users/tamirscherzer/POC/projects/NodeJS/tutorials/classes/main.js:5:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)

Really strange, if I change `require('./baseModel.js');` to other name, I get error that file not found so the path is written properly.

Also defined permissions `777` - same thing, `BaseModel is not defined`

Any Ideas?

Comment: Could be the case sensite of the name of the file, and the name of the class baseModel

Comment: When you `require`something, you need to assign the returned object to a name

Comment: export the class by prefixing export as follows `export class BaseModel{}`

Comment: yea you need to use es6 `export` or es5 `modules.export`

Comment: @NishanthShetty: Note that they're not using a transpiler, so the ES6 `import` and `export` syntax won't work. They have to use `require(...)` and `module.exports`.

Comment: @JoeClay that was never stated and neither was the version of Node which matters. However it was stated that they are learning Node ES6

Comment: You can see the current status of ES6 modules in Node [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es6-modules.md) - the specifics of how it's going to interoperate with the existing module system haven't fully been figured out, so it's still in the draft phase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you define a variable in Node, it isn't added to the global scope like it would be in a browser - it's local to that one file/module. Therefore, you can't simply import a file and expect the things you defined inside it to be available - you explicitly have to export and import them.

*BaseModel.js:*

```
class BaseModel {
  constructor(options = {}, data = []) { // class constructor
      this.name = 'Base'
      this.url = 'http://azat.co/api'
      this.data = data
      this.options = options
    }

    getName() { // class method
        console.log(`Class name: ${this.name}`)
    }
}

module.exports = BaseModel;
```

*AccountModel.js:*

```
"use strict";

let BaseModel = require('./baseModel.js');

class AccountModel extends BaseModel {
    constructor(options, data) {

    super({private: true}, ['32113123123', '524214691']) //call the parent method with super
      this.name += 'Account Model'
      this.url +='/accounts/'
    }


    get accountsData() { //calculated attribute getter
    // ... make XHR
        return this.data
    }

}

module.exports = AccountModel;
```

*main.js:*

```
"use strict";

let AccountModel = require('./AccountModel.js');

let accounts = new AccountModel(5)

accounts.getName()

console.log('Data is %s', accounts.accountsData);
```

Comment: great, works, so how to use `es6 export`  instead `modules.export` ?

Comment: @snaggs: They're not implemented in Node yet. You'd have to use a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to use ES6 imports and exports.